# Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ be a $n \times m$ matrix such that $AB$ is $I_m$. Show that we must have $m \le n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ be a $n \times m$ matrix such that $AB$ is the $m \times m$ identity matrix. Show that we must have $m \le n$.

I am not sure where to begin with this proof.

Comment: Consider the ranks of $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide some intuition building on @angryavain's hint, it helps to think of a matrix as an operator that does something to a vector.

- The matrix $\textbf{B}$, which is $n \times m$, sends an $m$-dimensional vector to an $n$-dimensional space.
- If the $n$-dimensional space $\textbf{B}$ sends the vector to is smaller than the original space the vector was in ($m$), this cannot be undone (this is where the matrix's rank comes in).
- However, in order for $\textbf{A}\textbf{B}$ to be the identity matrix, $\textbf{A}$ must be able to undo $\textbf{B}$.